# Laravel Seeder - how to seed null values on unique column

Tags: laravel

I've got simple User model:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    ...
}
```

I want to make a seeder that will not fill e-mail adresses that could be filled later by the user:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
    $user = new User();
    $user->save();
}
```

However I've got an obvious error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value

I tried to use User Model mutator for my seeder:

**User Model**

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
    if ( empty($value) ) { // will check for empty string
        $this->attributes['email'] = NULL;
    } else {
        $this->attributes['email'] = $value;
    }
}
```

**User Seeder**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmailAttribute('');
    $user->app_role = "user";
    $user->save();
}
```

but this is not working for me here, I'm getting an error again:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null

However, I don't want to set the `email` column to `unique` and `nullable` permanently, since I want to test this only for my seeder.

Anyone knows how to find a solution here?

Comment: you should set the column to `nullable`

Comment: Why don't you just fill the email column with dummy emails (maybe u can use faker) and ask the user to replace it later? and you can add an extra column which will keep a check that this email is fake or user-filled (a flag in other words).

Comment: @JunaidAhmad sure it can be done, but I'm not sure if this could be the best solution for me, will try this solution if no other could be done, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `nullable()` to your `email` column in your migration

```
    $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable()
```

then run the following in your command line,

1.`composer dump-autoload`  // updates the changes in your migration

2.`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` //new migration and seeds your seeders